# (Solving SQL problem using Pandas) from the given pandas df, find the person with most friends and number of friends

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

From the given df below,

```
request_accepted_short = pd.DataFrame({'requester_id':[1,1,2,3],
                                 'accepter_id':[2,3,3,4],
                                 'accept_date':['2016_06-03','2016_06-08','2016_06-08','2016_06-09']})
```

I want to find the person (requester_id and accepter_id both are the id of a person) with the most friends, and I also want to show the number of friends that person has. Based on above df, the person is 'id=3', and number of friends is 3.

This is rated as medium SQL problem in Leetcode, and I want to find the efficient, Pandaic way of solving this problem.

Here's what I tried. 
I concatenated the requester_id and accepter_id in one column, in order to see which id is most common in one column.

```
summary = pd.concat([request_accepted_short['requester_id'],request_accepted_short['accepter_id']])
```

Then, I used pandas .mode() to detect the most common id.

```
summary.mode()
```

With this process, it does get me to the most id with most friends, but this is far from best way to solve this.

My lack of understanding in 
1. how .concat() works and how .mode() works, and 
2. how pandas series and pandas dataframe work together, 
are obvious here.
Any help from pandas expert will be appreciated

Comment: are acceptor-requester pairs duplicated? if so do you want to count them twice, or only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use value_counts() to find the count of value with most occurence. Since value_counts is a Series method, you need to stack the two columns first

```
df[['requester_id','accepter_id']].stack().value_counts().reset_index(name = 'count').iloc[0]

index    3
count    3
```

The same would work using concat as you are trying,

```
pd.concat([df['requester_id'],df['accepter_id']]).value_counts()
```